# what is the address of default home page?

Tags: blog

By default we can see list of last notes, categories etc... int first page. After I installed WooCommerce I changed my home page to shoping page from settings->reading->front page. So far so good.
No I want to add a link to my top navbar which points to the old home page url. But I don't know what's the url.

Bottom line:
**I want to add a link to my blog.**

I don't want it to be the home page But I still need it !

Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Settings > Reading*, set a page as your blog page and the URL will be that page's URL.

Please note that depending on your theme it may not use the same template as your previous front page. You will need to talk to the theme author if that's a problem.

Comment: I've already set that to shopping page. I did know what's the shopping cart url before setting that as front display page. It is yourdomain.com/shop and it's working even after setting it as front display page. Now what I want is the url of my blog. Are my customers allowed to see last updates of my blog ? I think they should be.

Comment: What? There's two options: A front page, and the posts (blog) page. You have set your shop as the homepage, now set the posts page and that will be your blog.

Comment: It seems there was something wrong with the translation or plugins. I tested a  default installation in english and I saw what you said. Thank You.